# When trying to run onEdit(e) : - TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ macros.gs:18

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This is the code I am trying to run with no success:-

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  
 if (e.range.getA1Notation == "c19") {
 if (e.range.getValue == true) {
 
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
   spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showRows(1, 199);
  spreadsheet.getRange('58:199').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:M1').activate();
}
 }
}
```

In Google Sheets I am trying to run a macro that will hide rows when the value of a cell is TRUE

There will be more rows to unhide and hide in the same routine, but I am just trying to get the first bit to work.

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me.  You are trying to hide rows that have already be hidden.  It looks like you are misunderstanding what you are doing.  Try eliminating some lines and start with a simpler script.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you code does:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart == 19 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.hideRows(2,18);
    sh.showRows(1,199);
    sh.hideRows(58,142);
    sh.hideRows(2,18);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!!  Thank you so much, it works a treat!  Now that you have helped me with the basics if I get unstuck again with the rest of my spreadsheet please can I get in touch with you again?   I wish I had known about this forum, it would have saved me days of trying to work out the syntax.    :)

Comment: Hi Cooper I have come unstuck again.....  I am trying to do something I thought would be really easy but I can't get it to work.  I would like to hide row 85 when the cell value in T85 is equal to 1.  I would also like to know how to hide rows 83 to 88 if the same cell value in T85 is equal to 1.  Please can you help?

Comment: The important issue here is how does T85  values get change to one.  If it's due to a formula or another script operation then onEdit trigger will not fire.  Because onEdit triggers only fire for user edits.